# Spin-Lock and Busy-Wait

Tags: operating-systems

This question has been asked and the top answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38173155/12862537 is not satisfactory.

So, it would be nice if someone could specifically point out the similarities and differences between the two.

About the answer at the mentioned link:

> The term busy-waiting tends to mean that you are willing to spin and wait for a change in a hardware register or a memory location. The term does not necessarily mean locking, but it does imply waiting in a tight loop, repeatedly probing for a change.

Some unanswered queries:
Does this mean that spinlock waits without probing for change ?
If so, how does spinlock wait ?

The answer specially mentions that

> busy-wait waits for a change in hardware register or memory location

What is the reason to explicitly mention this ? Does spin-lock wait for something else ?

Comment: That's a pretty detailed answer.  You say that it is not satisfactory, without saying what specifically you don't understand or why you're not satisfied or what you would look for in an answer you're not satisfied with.  I worry someone is going to write a long answer and you're going to say you're not satisfied with that either.  We're looking for questions that provide clear criteria that people can use to evaluate answers and decide how to vote on them.  Also, we're looking for questions that come with research and explanation of what you've found so far and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you understand both concepts, you should be able to work out the similarities and differences on your own.  So, if you're not able to do that, is there some specific aspect of either one that you're not sure about?  It might be better to ask about that.

Comment: D.W. I wanted to write what I didn't like about that answer. I thought that it would be seen as a rant. Now that you have mentioned it I will update the question.

Comment: The answer says "it does imply waiting [..], repeatedly probing for a change" and you are asking "Does this mean that spinlock waits without probing for change?" - surely you can answer this on your own?

Comment: There is different intent.  Busy-waiting is a way to wait for something (not specified by the term 'busy-wait').  A spinlock busy-waits **in order to obtain a lock**.  The busy-wait is why its name says **spin** -- though these days with some internal consideration given to minimizing bus/memory contention, but that is mere detail.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @another-dave I now understand.